# PWA not updating on iOS Home Screen

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps

i´m currently facing an issue with my PWA on iPhone´s Home Screen.

See, my PWA works just fine in chrome and safari browser, caches all files, works offline and it updates when a new version is present. The problem comes when i add the app to iOS home screen and i make a new update, the app in Home Screen doesn't load the new version, unless i remove it from home screen and add it again from safari.

I've search the whole internet trying to find if someone has had the same issue but i can't find the solution.

Does anyone now what can be happening or how can i solve this?

Thanks in advance.